# Puzzle about spider in a shed of prism shape and shortest distance from one vertex to another.

Tags: geometry, puzzle

Spider likes to walk in a shed during the night. It can walk on its floor, walls, ceiling. The shed is a prism. Dimension of shed is `a x b x c`.

What is the closest way from start to finish?(image)

[image]

I think it can be.
$$
\sqrt[2]{a^2 + b^2} + c 
$$
or
$$
\sqrt[2]{a^2 + c^2} + b 
$$
or
$$
\sqrt[2]{a^2 + c^2} + a
$$

I bet it is the first option, but I do not know how to proove it.

Comment: How about $\sqrt{(a+b)^2+c^2}$ instead?  Telling your three options apart is impossible without knowing which of $a,b,c$ is the largest and which the smallest.

Comment: I've added the Project Euler tag.  This is problem 86.  http://projecteuler.net/problem=86

Comment: We can do slightly better.  Imagine unwrapping the box into six rectangles.  Identify the starting and ending points.  Then we get $\sqrt{(a+c)^2 + b^2}$ as our length (or $\sqrt{(a+b)^2+c^2}, \sqrt{(a+c)^2+a^2}$).  Intuitively, you're going across the center of each of the  rectangles formed.

Comment: the answer should be shorter. Remember a straight line is the shortest?

Comment: Related: [Is there a general solution for the “Spider and the Fly Problem”?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/271272/856)

Comment: @Mike The project-euler tag really seems incorrect.  This is a [well-known problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpiderandFlyProblem.html), not originally created by project euler and the question does not use the parameters used in project euler's version.

Comment: @Mike In fact, now that I actually read Project Euler problem 86, this problem is entirely different than that problem.

Comment: @Goos I think it's close that other readers can look and decide.  And in this problem and the Project Euler problem, the spider is in one corner and the fly in the opposite corner, something which, as far as I've seen so far, is not part of the problem in general.  You can't seriously believe that this formula would not be step one in solving problem 86.

Comment: @Mike "step one in solving problem 86" is not the same as being the same problem.  Given that this is a famous problem I don't really see why you assume the OP must be doing Project Euler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we unfold the prism, we can get a few nets. For now, we will take the nets with the 4 rectangles lined in a row. That means the top 6 in this picture. 
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Planificacao_cubo.gif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aPlanificacao_cubo.gif) 
Without loss of generality, let the side with 'a' on it be on the second rectangle. Using the nets, I will leave you to put the points down and draw the lines.

> When you've done that, remember phyto?