# Spider and fly problem on a Teserract.

Tags: geometry, optimization, solid-geometry

In [the spider and fly puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_spider_and_the_fly_problem), there is a spider on the inside of a cuboidal room wondering how it would get to a fly on another point on the inside of the cuboid. Here, we just "flatten out" the cuboid in different ways and take the shortest path across all of their shortest paths. Now, replace the cube with a Tesseract. If the spider is restricted to the cubical boundaries (it can now "fly in 3-d space") and the fly is similarly on another cubical boundary, the same algorithm can be extended. Just flatten it out in 3-d space every possible way and find the shortest straight-line path among them. But what do we do if the spider loses its new power and goes back to only crawling on the 2-d surfaces (and the fly is on one of those surfaces as well). Now the trick from before where we flatten out doesn't work anymore. It is impossible to flatten out a Tesseract onto a 2-d surface without having some faces overlap (see: [Prove that it isn't possible to flatten a Teserract into 2-d space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4454565/prove-that-it-isnt-possible-to-flatten-a-teserract-into-2-d-space?noredirect=1#comment9330226_4454565)). So what do we do now? How to find the shortest path between two points on the 2-d surfaces of a Tesseract? Is there no algorithm?

NOTE: The accepted answer here: [Is there a general solution for the "Spider and the Fly Problem"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271272/is-there-a-general-solution-for-the-spider-and-the-fly-problem?rq=1) in the 3-d case does require looping through unfoldings. The unfoldings are basically spanning trees. But for a given spanning tree, not sure how to get the shortest path without being able to "lay it flat".

Comment: Why does ""flattening out in different ways" not work here too?  There may be a difficulty that there are many more different ways, but that is a practical issue not a theoretical one

Comment: Imagine 2 cubes connected together and the common face between them is also accessible to the spider (and it can cross between the cubes once it reaches an edge of the common face). Once you flatten both cubes out, no way to lay the common face flat without it falling on an existing face. You get structures with this issue when you flatten the Tesseract to 3-d.

Comment: "Flattening out" isn't a technical necessity, it's a hack to bring our intuition of plane geometry to bear on the question. We can construct a data structure representing the $k$-skeleton (set of $k$-dimensional faces and incidence relations) of an $n$-dimensional cube without flattening at all.

Comment: How would this data structure method work for the original spider and fly puzzle?

Comment: @RohitPandey In the tesseract, if you go from one face onto one of its edges, then you will continue on to one of two other faces which share that edge.  That just makes the number of possible "different ways" bigger, but not impossible since for a shortest distance between two point there is a bound on the number of possible faces used

Comment: @Henry - but in the original puzzle, if not for the flattening, I wouldn't know where to land on the next face. Where to hit the connecting edge exactly.

Comment: @RohitPandey: One *could* approach the original problem as follows—identify each point on any edge by the pair $(x, y)$, where $x \in \{e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_{12}\}$ identifies which edge the point is on, and $y$ gives the distance of the point on that edge (relative to some reference point chosen for each edge). Then an edge-sequence can be identified that leads from beginning to end, and the optimization for that edge-sequence identifies which points on each edge minimizes the length of that edge-sequence. Finally, we collect all edge-sequences and pick that which minimizes the length.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking as well after Henry's comments. Would be nice to have a general way to do those optimizations for each edge sequence. BTW, the edge sequences can be obtained by getting rid of edges in a way that you still have a spanning tree and then moving along the remaining edges.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just a fleshing-out of my comment that is itself too long for a comment. Making it C-W in the hope of inviting others to contribute.

For simplicity, let's work in the cube $I^{n} = [-1, 1]^{n}$ in Euclidean $n$-dimensional space, whose vertices are $n$-tuples of $1$s and $-1$s. Everything combinatorial below extends with obvious modifications to a general box
$$
\prod_{j=1}^{n} [a_{j}, b_{j}] = [-a_{1}, a_{1}] \times [-a_{2}, a_{2}] \times \cdots \times [-a_{n}, a_{n}].
$$

By writing
$$
[-1, 1] = \{-1\} \sqcup (-1, 1) \sqcup \{1\}
$$
(disjoint union, hence $\sqcup$), we may index the set of all faces by ordered $n$-tuples $(e_{j})_{j=1}^{n}$ in $\{-1, I, 1\}^{n}$. We can usefully encode incidence data by defining
$$
\begin{array}{r|rrr}
  \cap & -1 & I & 1 \\
  \hline
  -1 & -1 & -1 & \varnothing \\
   I & -1 &  I & 1 \\
   1 & \varnothing & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
$$
and extending componentwise: $(e_{j}) \cap (e_{j}') = (e_{j} \cap e_{j}')$. An obvious modification defines containment.

- For $0 \leq k \leq n$, a $k$-face is the set of points where precisely $n - k$ coordinates are fixed and the remaining $k$ vary freely in $[-1, 1]$, namely a sequence with precisely $k$ components equal to $I$.
- Consequently, there are $2^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}$ faces of dimension $k$, parametrized by picking $k$ "free" components and setting the remaining $(n - k)$ components to either $-1$ or $1$.
- Two faces intersect if and only if the intersection of their formal representations has no "$\varnothing$" component.

The locations of a spider and a fly may be encoded as $n$-tuples $(x_{j})$ of real numbers in $I^{n}$; the smallest-dimensional containing face of each is found by setting each $x_{j}$ with $|x_{j}| < 1$ to $I$. If each lies in the $k$-skeleton (the union of faces of dimension at most $k$), a path from the spider to the fly may be constrained by permitting it to travel only in the $k$ skeleton, or not, as the case may be.

---

To finish with a couple of speculative strategies (since OP and others here are more knowledgeable about data structures and algorithms than I):

- One might prospectively calculate the distance to the fly recursively over faces, starting with the fly's lowest-dimensional containing face and extending to neighboring faces (perhaps of constrained dimension)  until reaching one of the spider's containing faces. The distance function over any particular $k$-skeleton is continuous, and (without having thought too hard) looks recursively tractable. On the other hand, there are $3^{n}$ faces, so this is not an effective idea if one is really concerned with $1000$-dimensional boxes.
- The distance function on the $1$-skeleton, and a shortest path, look easy to compute. If so, that gives an upper bound on the distance. One might then recursively shorten this path by (optimally?) pushing sequences of segments into higher-dimensional skeleta, analogously to cutting diagonally across a rectangular field.

In any case, a shortest path proceeds monotonically along the displacement vector from the spider to the fly, in the precise sense that if $x(t)$ is a piecewise-$C^{1}$ shortest parametrization starting at the spider $S$ and ending at the fly $F$, then $0 < x'(t) \cdot (F - S)$ for all $t$. That may usefully constrain the types of search needed.

Comment: WHy u made this community wiki?

Comment: @Aplateofmomos Because it's not an answer, but over time others may fill in missing details or remove irrelevant ones. :)