# Optimal path on the surface of cuboid doesn't visit the same face twice

Tags: geometry, optimization, solid-geometry

There is a room in the shape of the cuboid. A spider sits somewhere on one of the faces. And there is a dead fly on one of the faces as well. The spider wants to get to the fly along the shortest path by crawling along the faces of the cuboid. The optimal path should have the property that once it leaves a face of the cuboid, it doesn't come back to the same face again. Can we prove this?

EDIT: Context is a spider and fly riddle: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpiderandFlyProblem.html. I'm looking to develop an algorithm that finds an optimal solution in general (for any solid and positions of spider and fly) and this property is required for such an algorithm.

Comment: Say you have a path that does come back to the same face, can you cut out a portion of this path and paste something new in to replace it? Is this cut and paste path shorter than the path you had before?

Comment: Just open the faces flat and draw a straight line. When you find a path just rotate the start face by 180 degrees. If you will provide a specific case - will provide you with drawoings.

Comment: To add to what Moti has said, if a particular straight line exits the opened figure, you can exclude that part of the line as the figure is in reality closed, so that distance never gets covered in reality. Moreover, a straight line will never intersect a face once it has passed through it.

Comment: @DevanshBhardwaj and Moti- I'm looking for a proof to this "straight lines" claim. Might post a different question for it.

Comment: @RohitPandey Suppose you draw a circle with one point as radius and other as a point on circumference. Then would the radius not be the shortest path to it from the centre? An arbitrary curved path can be approximated by small line segments, and by appropriately segmenting the radius, it is visible that all these line segments will be hypotenuse to the line segments of the radius, thus the radius path would be shorted than any arbitrary path.

Comment: Don't follow this analogy with radius. Sorry. Squinted at it for a while.

Comment: Should we just continue this discussion in chat? I am having trouble understanding your viewpoint

Comment: A really general answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/275329/1030426.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AHusain's comment contains the answer, but it looks from the comments as if you didn't realise this. So to make it explicit:

Suppose the spider leaves a face at point $A$ and re-enters the same face at point $B$. Then the path that the spider took from $A$ to $B$ must necessarily be longer than the straight line from $A$ to $B$, which can be traversed without leaving the face.